# Multithreaded DbContext Operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

The following code (on a single DbContext) results in "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed".

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/[controller]/circuit")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAllCircuits()
{
    var circuits = await Task.WhenAll((await _context.Circuits.ToListAsync()).Select(async x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.FastestLap,
        x.LengthInMiles,
        Country = await _context.Countries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == x.CountryId),
        Map = await _context.Maps.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == x.MapId),
        Locations = await _context.Locations.Where(l => l.CircuitId == x.Id).ToListAsync()
    }));

    return circuits;
}
```

I was able to fix this by stripping out the `async/await` and `Task.WhenAll` parts, and replacing them with `.Result`, which seems to be a big no-no in .NET. Fixed example below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/[controller]/circuit")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAllCircuits()
{
    var circuits = (await _context.Circuits.ToListAsync()).Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.FastestLap,
        x.LengthInMiles,
        Country = _context.Countries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == x.CountryId).Result,
        Map = _context.Maps.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == x.MapId).Result,
        Locations = _context.Locations.Where(l => l.CircuitId == x.Id).ToListAsync().Result
    });

    return circuits;
}
```

My three questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is the "fixed" code clean? If not, please could you suggest a better approach?
3. Can I just use `.ToList()` rather than the async variant?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you write a "normal" LINQ to Entities query - no async things inside, `IQueryable<TResult>`, with just awaited final `ToListAsync()`? And use navigation properties instead of these "manual: joins.

Comment: 1. The reason you get the exception is because EF can't guarantee that the data it returns is still valid because another thread might have updated/deleted data from the DB.  2. Calling `.Result` on an async function is worse than just calling the synchronous version of the function (i.e. `ToList` instead of `ToListAsync`). 3.  Yes, but doing that would defeat the entire purpose of async programming. If you set up your database tables with foreign keys you should prefer navigation properties over manually loading from context (as @IvanStoev says)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

`DbContext` doesn't allow multiple operations on the same db connection. In this case, you have one call (`ToListAsync`) followed by multiple concurrent calls (the `Select`).

> Is the "fixed" code clean? If not, please could you suggest a better approach?

No. You shouldn't use `.Result`.

Your options are:

1. (Ideal) Change the LINQ query so that it includes all the necessary information in *one* query, e.g., using joins or includes. This is the ideal solution because there's only one query and the db server can handle it most efficiently.
2. Only do one operation at a time, since you only have one connection. This is why the `.Result` is working, but a better solution would be to use `await`, just do them one at a time instead of using `Select` with `Task.WhenAll`. The disadvantage to this approach is that the operations are only done one at a time.
3. Keep the multiple operations, and open up one db connection per operation. The disadvantage to this approach is that it requires multiple db connections.

> Can I just use .ToList() rather than the async variant?

The `ToListAsync` isn't the problem. The problem is `Select` + `WhenAll`.

Comment: Great thanks! Sometimes I guess it just takes a step back to look at the wider problem, rather than the immediate error. I'll give the first option a go now :)